# Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #date(2022, 3, 14) to type Logical

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery, m

I converted an excel formula over to power query to try to speed it up and filter before it enters the sheet, can I get some help on why im getting this error:
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #date(2022, 3, 14) to type Logical.
Details:
Value=3/14/2022
Type=[Type]

Here is the code line:

```
= Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "Custom", 
    each 
      if (
        if [PO_TYPE] = "Intransit ASN" then
          if [RECEIPT_DATE] = "" then
            Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
          else if [INV_ORG] = "GSN" then
            if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15 then
              Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE], 25)
            else
              [RECEIPT_DATE]
          else if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15 then
            Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE], 25)
          else
            [RECEIPT_DATE]
        else if [RECEIPT_DATE] = "" then
          Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
        else if [INV_ORG] = "GSN" then
          if Date.Day([NEED_BY_DATE]) > 15 then
            Date.AddDays([NEED_BY_DATE], 25)
          else
            [NEED_BY_DATE]
        else if Date.Day([NEED_BY_DATE]) > 15 then
          Date.AddDays([NEED_BY_DATE], 25)
        else
          [NEED_BY_DATE] < Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
      )
      then
        Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
      else if [PO_TYPE] = "Intransit ASN" then
        if [RECEIPT_DATE] = "" then
          Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
        else if [INV_ORG] = "GSN" then
          if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15 then
            Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE], 25)
          else
            [RECEIPT_DATE]
        else if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15 then
          Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE], 25)
        else
          [RECEIPT_DATE]
      else if [RECEIPT_DATE] = "" then
        Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
      else if [INV_ORG] = "GSN" then
        if Date.Day([NEED_BY_DATE]) > 15 then
          [NEED_BY_DATE] + 25
        else
          [NEED_BY_DATE]
      else if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15 then
        Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE], 25)
      else
        [RECEIPT_DATE]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just eyeballing it, it has to do with the first **if** above the red box

[image]

The code in the red box returns some form of date, shown by the blue boxes

So then your **if** statement gets evaluated as:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if( somedate else
```

and that is trying to use a date as a logical

As an aside, the code is not pretty. Do you want to explain what it is meant to do for some help on that?

Comment: Im not sure I understand. The entirety of the code should return a form of date, so every else is a date. 
I know the code isn't pretty working on cleaning it up but don't know exactly the function of it besides evaluating the two dates. To me it seems repetitive.

Comment: your code is doing IF ( bunch of code in red) ELSE (other bunch of code) .  The first bunch of code in the red box returns a date.  That makes the code evaluate as IF(DATE) ELSE which cannot be done   Assuming I have my levels wrong, the problem is the same.  You are returning a date to the very first IF

Comment: Also I see "[NEED_BY_DATE]+25" in the mishmash at the bottom. You need to use Date.AddDays

Comment: As a better idea, why don't you post the original formula you are trying to convert?

Comment: Here is the excel formula simplified:
`=IF([RECEIPT_DATE]="",TODAY(),IF(IF(DAY([RECEIPT_DATE])>15,[RECEIPT_DATE]+25,[RECEIPT_DATE])<TODAY(),TODAY(),IF(DAY([RECEIPT_DATE])>15,[RECEIPT_DATE]+25,[RECEIPT_DATE])))`
and here is the updated M code
`if [RECEIPT_DATE] = ""
then Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
else if
if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15
then Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE]),25)
else [RECEIPT_DATE]
<Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
then Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
else
if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15
then Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE]),25)
else [RECEIPT_DATE]
`

Comment: sorry, I'm  lost. Maybe someone else can help

Comment: thats ok, its a super odd formula, that could perhaps only be in  dax or excel language and doesnt work with M

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for your issue is that this parenthesis needs to be moved

```
[...]
        else if Date.Day([NEED_BY_DATE]) > 15 then
          Date.AddDays([NEED_BY_DATE], 25)
        else
          [NEED_BY_DATE] < Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
>>>   )    <<<
      then
        Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
      else if [PO_TYPE] = "Intransit ASN" then
        if [RECEIPT_DATE] = "" then
[...]
```

to before today's date:

```
[...]
        else if Date.Day([NEED_BY_DATE]) > 15 then
          Date.AddDays([NEED_BY_DATE], 25)
        else
          [NEED_BY_DATE] ) < Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
      then
        Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
      else if [PO_TYPE] = "Intransit ASN" then
        if [RECEIPT_DATE] = "" then
[...]
```

Apart from that, I would *strongly* recommend using variables to make your code more readable and more efficient. For example, your basic logic can be expressed more like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "Custom", 
    each 
        let
            rdate = 
                if Date.Day([RECEIPT_DATE]) > 15
                then Date.AddDays([RECEIPT_DATE], 25)
                else [RECEIPT_DATE], 
            today = Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), 
            tdate = if [RECEIPT_DATE] = "" then today else rdate
        in
            if tdate < today then today else tdate
  )
```